# Get Column DataType from Entity Framework Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

Using Entity Framework 5, database first.

Is it possible (at run time) to get the data type of the database column that an entity's property represents?  The .net type would also work fine if that's easier.

```
IEnumerable<DbEntityEntry> entities =
    context.ChangeTracker.Entries()
            .Where(
                e =>
                e.State == EntityState.Added || e.State == EntityState.Modified);

foreach (DbEntityEntry entity in entities)
{
   foreach (string propertyName in entity.CurrentValues.PropertyNames)
   {
     //so I know the entity and the property name.  Can I get the data type?
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use reflection on the entity to get the property info.

```
foreach (DbEntityEntry entity in entities)
{
    foreach (string propertyName in entity.CurrentValues.PropertyNames)
    {
        var propertyInfo = entity.Entity.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
        var propertyType = propertyInfo.PropertyType;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**To get the data type of the particular column of the table:**

[Assume: Entity prop class name: Vendors and column name ="VendorID"]

```
string columnTypName =   (context.Vendors.EntitySet.ElementType.Members["VendorID"].TypeUsage.EdmType).Name;
```

**To get all columns names and type of the columns dynamically**:

[Param : tableName]

```
var columns = from meta in ctx.MetadataWorkspace.GetItems(DataSpace.CSpace)
                                       .Where(m => m.BuiltInTypeKind == BuiltInTypeKind.EntityType)
                       from p in (meta as EntityType).Properties
                       .Where(p => p.DeclaringType.Name == tableName)
                       select new
                       {
                           colName = p.Name,
                           colType = p.TypeUsage.EdmType.Name
                       };
```

Comment: I got an error at `EntitySet`. "doesn't contain definition for EntitySet"

Comment: This is really useful because it allows you to get things like [`EntityProperty.MaxLength`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.entity.core.metadata.edm.edmproperty.maxlength.aspx) and [`EdmProperty.IsUnicode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.entity.core.metadata.edm.edmproperty.isunicode.aspx) without having to try to duplicate functionality already inside of EntityFramework.