# how to retrieve field type knowing the dbset

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

im sure this is something really simple
but i cant see the answer

here is my code:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Metadata.Edm;
using System.Data.Objects;


foreach (string f in fields) {                    
    string t = db.map_data.EntitySet.ElementType.Members[f].TypeUsage.EdmType.Name;
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("type = {0}", t);
}
```

basically i want to print out each column datatype 
i am referencing this post: [Get Column DataType from Entity Framework Entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18901720/get-column-datatype-from-entity-framework-entity)
however intellisense is giving me a red squiggly under EntitySet
so its not compiling because its not finding the assembly
but as noted above i included the proper assembly plus included a little extra

does anyone know what am i missing?

ps: i am using .net framework 4.0.2
but i checked with the ms page and apparently EntitySet is good this version

update: so thanks to pawel below
the reason why this doesnt work is cause map_data is a dbset not objectset
so the real question is then how can i get the column types of my model 
(during runtime) knowing the dbset

so basically 
id like to get this type of answer

```
Dictionary<string, string> fieldtypes = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach (string f in fields) {                    
    ... some thing happens here where i can set fieldtypes dictionary ...
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("{0} type = {1}", f, fieldtypes[f]);
}
```

Comment: What is `map_data`? A `DbSet` or an `ObjectSet`? Because `DbSet` does not have the `EntitySet` property.

Comment: aha! and therein lies the answer - thank you pawel - i will edit the post to reflect a better question knowing this info

Comment: The question is what you are trying to achieve? Where do you have `fields` from and why do you expect the the value returned from the Entity Type will be different because the mapping between O-Space and C-Space is 1:1...